# How to add pagination to custom query in CakePHP3

Tags: pagination, cakephp-3.0, finder

Here is my ClientsController:

```
namespace App\Controller\Api;

use App\Controller\Api\AppController;

class ClientsController extends AppController{
  public $paginate = [
    'page' => 1,
    'limit' => 5,
    'maxLimit' => 15,
    'fields' => [
         'id', 'name', 'user_id', 'dob', 'phone', 'email'
    ],
    'sortWhitelist' => [
        'id', 'name', 'user_id', 'dob', 'phone', 'email'
    ]
 ];




public function index(){
    $clients = $this->Clients->find('clients');
    $this->set([
                'clients'=>$clients,
                '_serialize'=>['clients']
                ]);

   }

}
```

Here is my custom Finder (ClientsTable):

```
 public function findClients(Query $query, array $options){
    $query
          ->select([
                'clients.id', 
                'clients.name'
            ])
            ->where(['clients.user_id =' => 3]);
    return $query;
}
```

How can I add pagination to this? This all works great it's just lacking pagination.

If I remove the index function I get pagination but then my finder doesn't seem to be called. This is how that code looks:

```
namespace App\Controller\Api;

use App\Controller\Api\AppController;

class ClientsController extends AppController{
  public $paginate = [
   'page' => 1,
   'limit' => 5,
   'finder' => 'clients',
   'maxLimit' => 15,
  'fields' => [
     'id', 'name', 'user_id', 'dob', 'phone', 'email'
   ],
  'sortWhitelist' => [
    'id', 'name', 'user_id', 'dob', 'phone', 'email'
  ]
];
}
```

Comment: So far the only way I can get this to work is by using this component:             https://github.com/bcrowe/cakephp-api-pagination

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding pagination value to json response in Cakephp 3.3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40225505/adding-pagination-value-to-json-response-in-cakephp-3-3)

Comment: It's not a duplicate, mine is trying to use a custom finder.

Comment: That doesn't matter, a finder is a finder, custom or built-in.

Comment: I disagree..... the built in finder 'all' worked for me but when I tried building my own I couldn't get the paginate option to show up in the results. Using the component above I was able to achieve this.

Comment: You not succeeding isn't the relevant factor though. The linked question is the same as your question, you both want to have pagination information in a JSON response, which is independent of what finder is being used.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have experience with using the "finder" option on the pagination array, but you should be able to just pass your query to the `paginate` function, along these lines:

```
$clients = $this->paginate($this->Clients->find('clients'));
```

Comment: Thanks for responding, I tried that but just get this as a response:{
  "clients": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Test Client 1",
      "user_id": 3,
      "dob": "12/18/1977",
      "phone": "715-572-5211",
      "email": "test1@test1.com",
      "clients": {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "Test Client 1"
      }
    }
  ]
}

Answer (score 0):

**You can try below code**

```
$this->loadComponent('Paginator'); /*Load the Paginator component*/
$clients = $this->Paginator->paginate($this->Clients->findClients()); /*Pass your finder method to the Paginator*/
```

Here is the documentation for directly use of Paginator components [Using the Paginator Directly](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/pagination.html#using-the-paginator-directly)

Comment: This isn't working either. I get the json result but there is no paginate property with it.

Comment: @bstras21 That's a totally different problem that you didn't mention in your question!